# Incorrect predictions when using the Keras pre-trained InceptionV3/Xception models

Tags: keras, deep-learning, tensorflow.js, pre-trained-model

I'm trying to get the pre-trained Keras InceptionV3/Xception models working in tensorflow.js. The models load perfectly fine, however the output predictions are far from correct (see InceptionV3 prediction photo)

I've also saved/converted the ResNet50 model, which is working perfectly fine.

Are these models simply incompatible with tensorflow.js currently? or is there something amiss with my code?

Models were saved/converted with the following:

```
from keras.applications import inception_v3
model = inception_v3.InceptionV3(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
model.save("InceptionV3.h5", False)

tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=keras InceptionV3.h5 InceptionV3
```

Code available here (angular app): https://github.com/BenMcFadyen/tfjs_test

The important part: https://github.com/BenMcFadyen/tfjs_test/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts

Versions:

- Chrome: 72.0.3626.109
- @tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0-alpha3

[InceptionV3 predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98c1x.png)

[ResNet50 predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKtD8.png)

Comment: You may want to add other tags like `keras`, `pretrained-model`, `deep-learning` to increase your chance of getting a response.

Comment: Just curious: do you plan to use the InceptionV3 model in browser or node.js? The model is quite large in terms of number of layers (>300) and would probably not run fast enough in the browser.

Comment: I tried converting InceptionV3 to TF.js format and loading it in TF.js (both Node.js and the browser). The results do differ between (Python) Keras and JavaScript. But the differences are mostly small (<1% relative difference between the probability scores). My guess is that numerical precision differences accumulate over the large number of layers and operations, leading to those differences. This looks similar to the GitHub issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1112

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! In my case the TF.js prediction results are very far from correct, with TF.js the top 3 results are: (flatworm, platyhelminth", 1), (pitcher, ewer", 2.24e-18), (binoculars, field glasses, opera glasses", 1.84e-22) Whereas when I test with Keras the top 3 results are: ('tabby', 0.44), ('Egyptian_cat', 0.25), ('tiger_cat', 0.062)
If you were able to receive accurate predictions, there must be something wrong with either the way I am converting the model, or with my image input process.

Comment: There is a possibility that it's due to a bug in the way the webGL backend of TF.js handles 1x1 conv2d kernels. See tracking issue at https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1270 Sorry for the inconvenience. We will fix it asap.

Comment: No worries, I'll try again once it's fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the issue for future reference, it turns out I wasn't normalizing the images into the range [-1, 1] before inputting them to the model as [Mobilenet](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/mobilenet) [does.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/6c02599b39607f566b1fd5514eae0306e603306b/mobilenet/src/index.ts#L118)
I'm not sure why the ResNet50 works without the normalization however.

Normalization code:

```
 let tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(canvas, number_channels);
 let normalizationOffset = tf.scalar(127.5);
 var normalized = tensor.toFloat().sub(normalizationOffset).div(normalizationOffset);
 var batched = resized.reshape([1, imgSize, imgSize, 3]);
 var output = model.predict(batched) as any;
```